# Invoke jquery datepicker for repeat jquery row inputs

Tags: jquery, html

How can I recall the datepicker js foreach of the new deploy_date inputs, it works fine on the first row but does not trigger on the new added rows.

```
   <div class="mt-repeater-input">
   <label class="control-label">Joined Date</label>
   <br/>
   <input class="input-group form-control form-control-inline date date-picker" size="16" type="text" value="" name="date-input" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" id ="addNew" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-success mt-repeater-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script><script src="{{ asset('js/date_pair.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/global/plugins/jquery-repeater/jquery.repeater.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/pages/scripts/form-repeater.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i tried with

```
 <script>
    $('#addNew').click(function(){
    $(".date-picker").datepicker("destroy"); //Destroy the date picker.

    /* Code to add a new row */

    jQuery( ".date-picker" ).datepicker(); //recreating the date picker

})
```

Comment: Show how you are adding new rows?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: I am using https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater,  the repeating is working fine just the date-picker isn't invoked.

Answer (score 0):

solved it with the following script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.form-group-2').repeater();

    $(".date-picker").focus(function(){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker();
        $(".timepicker.timepicker-24").timepicker({

            showMeridian: false
        });
    });

    $('.mt-repeater-add').click(function(){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker();
        $(".timepicker.timepicker-24").timepicker({

            showMeridian: false

        });

    })

});
```